# Stream Key in azure media service live streaming

Tags: azure-media-services, obs

I have created channel and program in azure media service. Both are running and I have Ingest URL. But OBS Studio asks me for "stream key". I tried providing "default" as suggested in "https://medium.com/@dsayed/live-streaming-with-microsoft-azure-eb6408d31ed" , but it is not working. Please let me know if I am missing anything or how to obtain streaming key in azure.

Regards,
Navaneeth

Answer (score 1):

If the stream key is maybe what Wirecast called a "stream name" ; you can put whatever you want ('default' or 'mystream', etc).
Please make sure to put the full ingest RTMPs ingest in OBS, including the token generated by Media Services.
For example : 
rtmps://02df50c7c69e4f138a25909axxxxxxxx.channel.media.azure.net:1935/live/99cf7a5638404205b32582xxxxxxxxxx